# Loading reference to new version throws exception saying it's looking for old version

Tags: c#, assemblies, prism, nuget

I have several assemblies that referenced Prism (version 4) assemblies that I had in the directory I extracted Prism to. I wanted to switch over to NuGet, so I removed all of those references, and installed the packages via NuGet and chose to install the packages to all the same assemblies as before. Prism 4.1 was now being referenced. The solution built fine (clear and rebuild).

Then, when I run the application, as soon as it tries to create an object that uses a Prism references,
I get a "FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Interactivity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference"

I verified that the 4.1 dlls were in my "bin" folder, so I know the files exist. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what version of .NET are you compiling.. have you tried to compile this as a 3.5 version then recompiling this as a 4.0 project.. also make sure that the old .DLL's are not being GAC'd I would actually start looking there first..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I accidentally missed an assembly when installing the packages from NuGet. This one assembly was being referenced by the assembly my object is in that I was trying to create. I installed the 4.1 package to this other assembly and everything works as expected.